# How do I load code into a specified directory using Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have the situation where our code base is like so:

/Gui/

/Product1/

/Calc engine/

/Core/

/Product2/

All of these projects are loaded into a Global solution file in Visual Studio.

I want to extract Core to it's own repo and allow different branches of this repo to load different versions of it.  I cannot just use references to the binaries as engineers want to be able to debug the core code when running the Products so I have to be able to bring the entire Core codebase in.

Originally, I intended to use git submodules but I am investigating whether Nuget might be a better solution.  I have removed /Core/ to it's own repo and created a Nuget package of the Core directory (it contains about 20 different C# projects).

Is there a way I can input this Nuget package into the Global Solution?  It would need to put the code into the same directory as it used to rather than a package director.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can input this Nuget package into the Global Solution? It would need to put the code into the same directory as it used to rather than a package director.

You can change the Package Management to "Pakcage.config" in Options\Nuget Package Manager. The package will be stored in solution directory.

[image]

[image]

and right-click the solution in solution explorer then click "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution"
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  When I do this though I select the Nuget package  in the Nuget manager it gives a list of projects rather than just the solution.  The Nuget package contains a directory of projects to be integrated into this solution, is there a way of just loading the package once for the solution and not on a per project basis?

Comment: As far as I know, the nuget package is based on project instead of solution. So I'm afraid that you cannot  do that.